# Is it okay to get a letter of recommendation from my employer who is a scientist but not an Ph,D?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, recommendation-letter

I've worked for 3 years in the same field which I'm going to apply in. And my boss belongs to the same field too. He completed his M.tech.

I am taking three LOR's. Two from qualified Ph.D professors from my undergrad and one from my boss who works in research but is not a Ph.D.

Answer (score 3):

When reading a letter, the specific academic qualifications of the writer are not that important, judging their knowledge is. You say he works in research, so presumably he can gauge your technical skills (unlike, say, some administrator that just handles your payroll).
Furthermore, if your boss has enough experience supervising people, he can give a better assessment than someone who only has had one student.

In any case, you already have two letters from experienced professors. A third from a more junior person that has worked closely with you is still valuable, and not everybody has worked with three different professors. So you are fine from two different perspectives. It is up to the reader if they want to ask for them, or read them, or not. My girlfriend, for example, gave both her supervisor and a postdoc for an industry research job, but they only asked the professor and she got hired.

---

One caveat: the recommendation letter culture in academia and industry is very different. Make sure your boss is aware of that. A letter saying:

> Eren has worked in my group in COMPANY with the title POSITION between 2015 and 2018.

may be what is expected in industry, but it is a field of red flags in academia because he doesn't have anything nice to say about you.

Comment: *because he doesn't have anything nice to say about you* --- Better might be "because he doesn't explicitly say anything nice about you, which is often interpreted in academia as meaning that he doesn't have anything nice to say about you".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should definitely get a letter from someone who has supervised your work for multiple years.  In fact, if you do not get that letter, people will wonder why it is missing.

Admissions is interested in your qualities, not the qualities of your letter writer.

I agree with Davidmh that it is important the letter writer knows the letter writing customs of the people reading your letter.  These vary some by region.